# Fatal error:call to undefined method stdClass::xpath()

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml, php-5.4

I have this XML:

```
<JobReference> <Type>STANDARD</Type> <Title>N° ANCIEN DOSSIER</Title> <Reference/>
```

And am running this PHP code:

```
$xmljobreference = simplexml_load_string ($GetJobResult->JobReferences->JobReference->Title );    
$referenceanciendossier = $GetJobResult->JobReferences->xpath( "//JobReference[@Title ='N°  ANCIEN DOSSIER']/Reference" );
```

But I am getting this error:

> Fatal error:call to undefined  method stdClass::xpath() on line 190

If I run `var_dump($GetJobResult)` I get:

```
 public 'JobReferences' => 
    object(stdClass)[149]
      public 'JobReference' => 
        array (size=7)
          0 => 
            object(stdClass)[150]
              ...
          1 => 
            object(stdClass)[151]
              ...
          2 => 
            object(stdClass)[152]

             public 'JobSeq' => int 920179
```

Comment: Debug. Is $GetJobResult set?

Comment: well stdClass objects dont have methods... Probably you want to do something with `$xmljobreference`

Comment: @Gustaf i add var_dump($GetJobResult) it's Object

Comment: @test I provided an answer. Try that

Comment: @Gustaf i try but i have this error  call to undefined stdclass::xpath() and i put comment under your answer

Comment: I've just edited your question because the formatting made it impossible to read, but I'm still not at all clear what your code is doing. What is the line with `$xmljobreference` trying to do? How does the invalid snippet of XML you've posted relate to the partial output of `var_dump`? Try putting together a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), to help both yourself and us understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as your `var_dump` shows you, `JobReferences` is built up by a `JobReference` which itself is an array with 7 items.

So assuming that you want to run the xpath function on all the array items, you need to run a `foreach` loop. Something like this should work:

```
$array = $GetJobResult->JobReferences->JobReference;
$results = array();

foreach($array as $reference){
    array_push($results, $reference->xpath( "//JobReference[@Title ='N°  ANCIEN DOSSIER']/Reference" ));
}
var_dump($results);
```

Comment: in xml i have this <JobReference>
                  <Type>STANDARD</Type>
                  <Title>N°  ANCIEN DOSSIER</Title>
                  <Reference/>

Comment: can you tell me please how can i resolve this issue Thanks